# multiple criteria search using php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm relatively new to php/mysql combo. I've seen this questions being posted many times but could not find the answer to it that would help me. 
I have a table like this:

```
    "CREATE TABLE sample_table (
     id_sample smallint(6) NOT NULL auto_increment, 
     sample1 varchar(20) NOT NULL,
     sample2 varchar(20) default NULL,
     sample3 varchar(20) default NULL,
     sample4 enum('x1','x2','x3') NOT NULL default 'x1',
     ..
     ..
     samplexx varchar(20) default NULL,
     sample_last varchar(20) default NULL, 
     PRIMARY KEY  (`id_sample`)
     );"
```

Did a registration form where users fill all the required field. Now I need to do a 'user search' form where admins can search users by one or more fields.

```
    <form id="sample" name="sample" action="sample.php" method="post">
    <p> Sample1: </p><input type="text" name="sample_f1" id="sample_f1"/> 
    <p> Sample2: </p><input type="text" name="sample_f2" id="sample_f2"/>
    ..
    ..
    <p> Samplexx: </p><input type="text" id="sample_fxx" name="sample_fxx"/>
    <input id="search" name="search" type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
```

I am not sure if I'm using the right approach to this problem but here is how I started my php:

```
    include_once('common.php');
    $dbLink=dbConnect();
    if (isset($_POST['sample']))
    {
      $v[0] = $_POST['sample_f1'];
      $v[1] = $_POST['sample_f2'];
      ..
      ..
      $v[xx] = $_POST['sample_fxx'];
      $temp = "";
      $temp2 = "";
      $counter = 0;
      for ($i=0;$i<xx;$i++)
      {
        if($v[$i] == "" || $v[$i] == "NULL")
        {
          switch ($i)
          {
                case "0":
                $temp = $temp ."sample1,";
                break;
                case "1":
                $temp = $temp ."sample2,";
                break;
                ..
                ..
                case "xx":
                $temp = $temp ."samplexx,";
                break;
           }
         }
         else
         {
           $counter++;
           switch ($i)
           {
                 case "0":
                 $temp2 = $temp2 ."sample1='" .$v[$i] ."'*";
                 break;
                 case "1":
                 $temp2 = $temp2 ."sample2='" .$v[$i] ."'*";
                 break;
                 ..
                 ..
                 case "xx":
                 $temp2 = $temp2 ."samplexx='" .$v[$i] ."'*";
                 break;
           }
         }
       }
       $pieces = explode("*", $temp2);
       $some_var = $pieces[0];
       if($counter>1)
       {
         for ($i=1;$i<$counter;$i++)
         {
           $some_var = $some_var . " AND " .$pieces[$i] ;
         }
       }
       $query = "SELECT " .$temp ."sample_last FROM sample_table WHERE " .$some_var .";";
       $result = mysql_query($query, $dbLink);
       $result_count = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

So my basic idea was to save values from all the fields into one array and then check which fields were empty. Empty field are what I'm looking for and others are my criteria. My problem now is that I don't know neither how many fields/values I'm getting from database nor what fields are those. Now, for 'how many', I could use a counter and put all the data into a matrix, than figure out the way to put each data into correct place on my 'display data div'.

So my questions are:

Can 'multiple criteria search' be done this way? 
or 
How do you do 'multiple criteria search'?

Any idea, personal experience and/or example (does not have to be actual program code) is more than welcome.

Regards,
Coding_for_fun

I see you don't quite get what I was asking for so here's some more explanation (can't post images because I'm new user here). Let's say I have seven fields by which I can do a search. If I try to do a search for all records in db that have field sample1 = some_value and also field sample7 = some_value2. My query would than be:

```
    SELECT sample2,sample3,sample4,sample5,sample6,sample_last FROM sample_table WHERE sample1='some_value' AND sample7='some_value2';
```

I could just use

```
    SELECT * FROM sample_table WHERE sample1='some_value' AND sample7='some_value2';
```

but then I ask for many more data than I actually need. I hope this clarifies the problem here a bit.

So once more, I'm just asking for your ideas/personal experience when dealing with advanced searches like this.It does not have to be actual program code.

Comment: Lets see if I got it: You have 4 fields (for example) if the user fills one or more fields, you want to populate the rest of the fields from the database. Is that right?

Comment: Not quite. I need to pull up all the records from db that meet that criteria and display them while keeping 'search form' available for user to search with new criteria.

Comment: what is your final query add it here it's gives more clarity

Answer (score 0):

I see no one answered this so I'll put my solution to this problem (**I would still like to see other ideas**).

I was thinking: if I was able to put all variable names and values into one array to send it as query for SQL there must be a way to get them back from that array to original state. Here's what I did: (continued from the former php)

```
  if ($result_count > 0)
  {
    for ($i=0;$i<$result_count;$i++)
    {
        $result_set[$i]=mysql_fetch_row($result);
    }
    $variable_name = explode(",", $temp);
    $new_counter = 7 - $counter; // 7 because I had 7 fields by which user can search
    $variable_name_searched_temp = "";
    $variable_value_searched_temp = "";
    foreach ($pieces as &$piece) 
    {
        $temp = explode("=", $piece);
        $variable_name_searched_temp .= $temp[0] ."*";
    }
    $pieces = array_slice($pieces, 0, -1); //for some reason I had to do this before asking for second part ([1]) of that array
    //if you know why I needed that line of code please give me an explanation in a comment below
    foreach ($pieces as &$piece) 
    {
        $temp = explode("'", $piece);
        $variable_value_searched_temp .= $temp[1] ."*";
    }
    $variable_name_searched = explode("*", $variable_name_searched_temp);
    $variable_value_searched = explode("*", $variable_value_searched_temp);
    for ($i=0;$i<$result_count;$i++)
    {
        for ($j=0;$j<$counter;$j++)
        {
          switch ($variable_name_searched[$j])
          {
            case "sample1":
            $sample1 = $variable_value_searched[$j];
            break;
            case "sample2":
            $sample2 = $variable_value_searched[$j];
            break;
            ..
            ..
            case "samplexx":
            $samplexx = $variable_value_searched[$j];
            break;
          }
        }   
        for ($j=0;$j<$new_counter;$j++)
        {
          switch ($variable_name[$j])
          {
            case "sample1":
            $sample1 = $result_set[$i][$j];
            break;
            case "sample2":
            $sample2 = $result_set[$i][$j];
            break;
            ..
            ..
            case "samplexx":
            $samplexx = $result_set[$i][$j];
            break;
          }
          $sample_last = $result_set[$i][$j+1]; 
        }
        ?>
          <br><p> Sample1:  <?php echo $sample1; ?></p>
          <br><p> Sample2: <?php echo $sample2; ?></p>
          ..
          ..
          <br><p> Samplexx: <?php echo $samplexx; ?></p>
          <br><p> Sample_last: <?php echo $sample_last; ?></p>
        <?php 
    }
  }
```

I tested this and it works. Of course I still need to form this on my 'display data div', that HTML at the end was just to check if my code works.

You can see on those commented lines I have one line of code that I don't know why I had to put in.

```
    $pieces = array_slice($pieces, 0, -1);
```

As I said I'm relatively new to PHP/MySQL so can someone please explain to me why do I need that? (If I comment that line of code I get error: Undefined offset: 1)

And once more...I would still like to see other ideas when dealing with advanced searches so if you do this some other way please share it with me.

Regards, Coding_for_fun.